# Why I can't console.log this function?

Tags: javascript, html, api, async-await

```
let fetchPokemons = async() =>{
    for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        await getPokemon(i);
    }
}


let getPokemon= async id => {
    let response1 = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
    let pokemon = await response1.json();
    pokedex(pokemon);
}

function pokedex(pokemon){
    console.log(pokemon.types)
}

fetchPokemons();
```

I am trying to create a Pokedex. 
From my understanding this code does the following:

FetchPokemon function will run first. 
Inside it, getPokemon will Run.

After getting the response from API Pokedex function will run.

So I am testing whether pokemon data are coming back or not by console.logging the pokemon.types inside Pokedex function.

So Am I understanding wrongly?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with the given code?

Comment: If this is running in a website, I'm guessing OP is getting a CORS error.  OP, are you getting errors in your browser console?  If so, please share them with us.

Comment: That API actually has a wildcard CORS. How nice of them

Comment: @Amy { SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data }

I got this error only

Comment: You are not awaiting  your async method fetchPokemons() and there is no pokemon at index 0.

Comment: Add await to fetchPokemons(). Change your look to be `let i = 0; i <=50` and it will work

Comment: @KevinB Idk But i am not getting the console.log :(

Comment: @LukaszBalazy Can U post the working answer for me :D

Answer (score 2):

The API 404s if you ask for the 0th pokemon.  The 404 causes an exception that kills your for loop.  Try with this:

```js
function pokedex(pokemon) {
  console.log(pokemon.types)
}

async function getPokemon(id) {
  let response1 = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
  let pokemon;
  try { // Catch the 404 or response error if it happens so loop doesn't die
    pokemon = await response1.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  pokedex(pokemon);
}

async function fetchPokemons() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) { // Start at 1 instead of 0
    await getPokemon(i);
  }
}

fetchPokemons();
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you start with index 0 and https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/0 returns 404. you need to change 0 with 1:

```
for(let i = 1; i < 50; i++)
```